# Is there a way to use Adobe Creative SDK without logging the user in?

Tags: ios, aviary, adobecreativesdk

Aviary didn't need any login from the users, I want to use it but Creative SDK ask the users to login to an Adobe Account. I just want to be able to do simple editing stuff on device. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you have an Aviary account already I'd suggest using it since Adobe Creative is bad, complicated and is bigger in size.

Answer (score 5):

**Image Editor and Auth**
The Creative SDK Image Editor component doesn’t require login today, and there are no plans to have the core image editing tools be behind auth in the future.

[Details for getting started with the Image Editor are here](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/ios/#/articles/imageeditor/index.html).

**SDK Size**
To keep the size of your app down, the Creative SDK is broken up into smaller frameworks. You can choose to add only what you need to your dependencies.

[Details for Creative SDK framework dependencies are here](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/ios/#/articles/dependencies/index.html).

Comment: Did they remove the login feature?

Comment: User Auth exists in the SDK, but is not required for the core image editing tools. 

If you want Creative SDK User Auth in your app, you would add it in to your app in addition to the Creative SDK Image Editor.

Comment: You don't need login but you do still need to have a client key and secret  available from https://creativesdk.adobe.com/myapps.html and to call (with those values substituted in this call appropriately):[[AdobeUXAuthManager sharedManager] setAuthenticationParametersWithClientID:CreativeSDKClientId clientSecret:CreativeSDKClientSecret enableSignUp:true];

Comment: @AshRyan Is it free for unlimited edits on iOS and Android? I saw some 250,000 save per month limit on one page and on another it said unlimited..

Comment: @AshRyan Interesting, since the Getting Started guide claims that "Authentication is part of every Creative SDK workflow and every action performed requires a logged-in user." https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/ios/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html

Comment: For the Image Editor only, this isn't the case. However, if you want to provide your users access to Additional Content in the Image Editor, that does require User Auth ([knowledge base article here](https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/207914166-Getting-Additional-Content-for-the-Image-Editor-iOS-and-Android-)).