# Is there a way to use adobe creative sdk [i want to use only adobe labs magic selection tool] without login?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-editing, adobecreativesdk

I'm using adobe labs magic selection tool, but it asks the user for adobe sign in. Is there any way to not make the user login, but still use the magic selection tool? 
I heard about this, but couldn't implement. [See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491144/is-there-a-way-to-use-adobe-creative-sdk-without-logging-the-user-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe ID signin is required for Creative SDK Adobe Labs tools. There is no way to turn this off.